# Trigonometric Inequality involving $\sin x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

[image]
[image]

Can anyone help me out to answer this question?

Comment: I think you should type your question as it shows your seriousness for this question and this forum.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I am sorry for posting photos. Can you give the link where I can see How to typeset Mathematics

Comment: The best advise one can give is : jump directly into the swimming pool: type text with mathematical latex formulas when you know them (don't forget to enclose them between dollar signs)  and with words when you don't know them. For example the sign $\in$ is rendered by an antislash immediatly followed by the word "in", $\pi$ is rendered by antislash followed by "pi",  If you want to make $x_i$, type x, then "underscore " then i, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $(0,\pi)$, we have $\sin a_k>0$, thus, as $\ln$ is an increasing function, the problem is equivalent to prove that the logarithms of LHS and RHS are in the same order, i.e., dividing by $n$:

$$\tag{1} \frac{1}{n}\sum \ln(\sin(a_k)) \leq \ln(\sin(x)) \ \ \text{with} \ \  x:=\frac{1}{n}\sum a_k$$

As composite function $f:=\ln \circ \sin$ is concave ($f''(x)=-\dfrac{1}{\sin^2(x)}<0$), (1) appears as a consequence of classical Jensen's inequality for concave functions (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JensensInequality.html).

Comment: Maybe $x:=\frac{1}{n}\sum(a_k)$?

Comment: You are right, I hadn't sufficiently well read the question. I correct it.